# How to create an interactive map of a stars object that has a time dimension?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, mapview, r-stars

**Problem**

I have regular raster data with a time dimension. It comes as a `stars` object with the dimensions `x, y, date`.

*I want to visualize the stars raster with a timeslider (like [this one](https://dwilhelm89.github.io/LeafletSlider/) or similar) - to show every point in time.*

Unfortunately `mapview` cannot handle the time dimension out of the box, maybe a plain leaflet solution or even a shiny app is needed to do that.

Any ideas?

**Reproducible Example**

```
library(stars)
library(mapview)

n <- 2
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(rep(c(1:n), times = n), times = n),
  y = rep(rep(c(1:n), each = n), times = n),
  value = seq(1:(n * n * n)),
  date = rep(seq(
    as.Date("2023-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = n
  ), each = n * n)
)

df
#   x y   value     date
# 1 1 1     1 2023-01-01
# 2 2 1     2 2023-01-01
# 3 1 2     3 2023-01-01
# 4 2 2     4 2023-01-01
# 5 1 1     5 2023-01-02
# 6 2 1     6 2023-01-02
# 7 1 2     7 2023-01-02
# 8 2 2     8 2023-01-02


# Create stars object with time dimension from df
stars_with_time <- stars::st_as_stars(df,
                                      dims = c("x", "y", "date"))

# assign arbitrary crs
stars_with_time <- st_set_crs(stars_with_time, 25833)

# Now mapview disregards the time dimension
mapview(stars_with_time)
```

[image: mapview interactive map without time dimension]